# WORKING URL with capital letters to lowercase rule for mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I tried both (mod_rewrite) rules from http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase.html

But they ain't working.

http://www.example.com/de/Accessoire -> 404, it doesn't rewrite to http://www.example.com/de/accessoire

I have restarted Apache after putting the rules in httpd.conf.

Does anyone have a WORKING rule, replacing uppercase letters to lowercase in the requested URL ?

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]
```

and from the link above the very long one with the gotos/loops.. none of them did work.

I didn't put up `RewriteBase`, is this necessary?

Comment: What is the rewrite rules that you actually used?

Comment: @MichaelHampton updated my question!